# Difference between any and parametric polymorphism scala?

Tags: scala

I know that parametric polymorphism is what actually works, but I'm curious why using Any in it's place does not. For example how is the first function

```
def len[T] (l:List[T]):Int = 


 l match {
    case Nil    => 0
    case _ :: t => 1 + len(t)
  }
```

different from this one?

```
def len (l:List[Any]):Int = 
  l match {
    case Nil    => 0
    case _ :: t => 1 + len(t)
  }
```

Comment: You can even define it as `def len(l:List[_]):Int =` since `T` is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it doesn't work?  This seems fine:

```
len(List('a,'b,'c))
// res0: Int = 3
```

Your in your example, there really isn't a difference, since you're not actually using the contents of the list for anything, but imagine a slightly different function:

```
def second[T](l: List[T]): Option[T] = 
  l match {
    case Nil    => None
    case _ :: Nil    => None
    case _ :: x :: _ => Some(x)
  }

println(second(List(1,2,3)).map(_ + 5))                           // Some(7)
println(second(List(List('a,'b,'c), List('d,'e))).map(_.head))    // Some('d)
```

If you tried this with `Any`, you wouldn't be able to get anything except `Option[Any]` in return, so the compiler wouldn't let you do anything useful with the result (like add it to an `Int` or call `.head`, as in the examples, respectively).

Comment: well then what woulb be the difference if I used the contents of a the list

Answer (score 0):

In this case there really isn't a difference, because you aren't relying on the contained type at all, just the structure of `List` itself. It doesn't matter what `T` is, the length will be the same either way.

The type parameter would be important if you wanted to return another `List[T]`. For example:

```
def takeEveryOther[T](l: List[T]): List[T] =
    l.zipWithIndex.collect { case (a, i) if(i % 2 == 0) => a }
```